# Spark 2.0.0 is unable to parse the following JSON

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am parsing the following JSON  in spark which is a output of Influxdb, spark is going into some loop and results are never getting returned

```
{"results":[{"series":[{"name":"mos-st.builds","columns":    ["time","number","name","node"],"values":[["2016-11-29T11:00:04Z",74,"ScaleWindowsNodes",null],["2016-11-29T11:00:05Z",90720,"team-admin/Empty job","Job-manager-Machine ami-2a2e2842 (i-8262098c)"],["2016-11-29T11:00:07Z",74,"ScaleWindowsNodes",null],["2016-11-29T11:00:10Z",3022,"team-search/seed-8449","Job-manager-Machine ami-2a2e2842 (i-8262098c)"],["2016-11-29T11:05:00Z",3023,"team-search/seed-8449",null],["2016-11-29T11:20:05Z",90724,"team-admin/Empty job","Job-manager-Machine ami-2a2e2842 (i-8262098c)"],["2016-11-29T11:20:09Z",3026,"team-search/seed-8449","Job-manager-Machine ami-2a2e2842 (i-8262098c)"],["2016-11-29T11:25:00Z",90725,"team-admin/Empty job",null],["2016-11-29T11:25:00Z",3027,"team-search/seed-8449",null],["2016-11-29T11:25:05Z",90725,"team-admin/Empty job","Job-manager-Machine ami-2a2e2842 (i-8262098c)"],["2016-11-29T11:25:10Z",3027,"team-search/seed-8449","Job-manager-Machine ami-2a2e2842 (i-8262098c)"],["2016-11-29T11:30:00Z",90726,"team-admin/Empty job",null],["2016-11-29T12:10:00Z",90734,"team-admin/Empty job",null],["2016-11-29T12:10:05Z",90734,"team-admin/Empty job","Job-manager-Machine ami-2a2e2842 (i-8262098c)"],["2016-11-29T12:10:09Z",3036,"team-search/seed-8449","Job-manager-Machine ami-2a2e2842 (i-8262098c)"]]}]}]}
```

The code is given below:

```
 val df = sqlContext.read.json("<location>/sample.json")
```

Comment: Works just fine for me. Please try to create a [mcve].

Comment: I am using Spark 2.0 and Zeppelin 0.6.1 and this not just working for me. This is varifiable example. Open Zeppelin, copy the json text into a file and use the code given above,